# "We weren't all happy" — does that mean some of us or all of us?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, negation, syntactic-analysis

> We weren't all happy with the result.

Does this mean "All of us weren't happy with the result" or "Not all of us were happy with the result"?

Comment: *At least one of us was unhappy with the result.*

Comment: "We weren't all" = "Not all of us were". "We all weren't" = "All of us were not". Your two different meanings are conveyed through different word orders.

Answer (score 4):

It could mean either, although it probably means the latter, that **not all of us were happy with the result**.

For it to mean that everyone was not happy with the result, you would have to assume that either:

(1) The word **all** is misplaced:

> We **all** weren't happy with the result.

or (2) The speaker omitted the word "that":

> We weren't all [that] happy with the result.

But it's better not to assume anything and conclude it's the latter.